# Highlight duplicates, ignoring same row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet containing names in 2 dimensions. Each row represents a general location, every other column represents a specific slot in that location (each location has the same number of available slots), alternating with a parameter belonging to that name. There is a name in each cell. Here's a simplified version to show what my data looks like:

```
Location  0     ( )   1     ( )   2     ( )   3     ( )
Garden    Tim   3     Pete  1     Oscar 1     Lucy  2
Room1     Lucy  1     Tim   1     Lucy  5     Anna  1
Kitchen   Frank 1     Frank 2     Frank 1     Lucy  1
```

What I want to achieve is to highlight *(using conditional formatting, I'm open to alternative methods though)* each entry that also appears in another row. So basically it should highlight duplicates, but ignore duplicates in the same row. The first row and column are to be excluded from the operation (no big deal, I just don't select them), as are the parameter columns (this is a big deal, as this pretty much breaks everything I've tried including the first answers given). I have access to the entire meaningful data area (all cells containing names) by the name "entries" and all meaningful entries in a given row by the name "row".

In my example above, **all** `Tim` and `Lucy` entries should be highlighted because they have duplicates in other rows. `Pete`, `Oscar` and `Anna` are unique, so they're not highlighted. `Frank`, while having duplicates, only has them in the same row, no other row contains `Frank`, so he should not be highlighted. Excel's own highlight duplicates would highlight `Frank`, while handling all the others correctly.

How can I modify the conditional formatting's behaviour to ignore duplicates in the same row?

The following formula (thanks to @Dave) resulted in a `#VALUE!` error:

```
=(COUNTIF(entries;B2)-COUNTIF(row;B2))>0
```

Comment: where are you putting the formula? In the sheet somewhere, or in the conditional formatting box?

Comment: @user The conditional formatting box. Actually, since that resulted in simply nothing being highlighted, I put it into a random cell to see what it results in (both in the conditional `>1` form and the raw value), which is where I got the error. I even split it into both parts, both resulted in the error. I tested to find out why and found that the `COUNTIF` returned the error whenever the first argument was not a range of connected cells, but rather a concatenation of ranges.

Comment: please select `B2:I2`  and put  this (exactly) in the conditional formatting box: `=COUNTIF($B$2:$I$4;$B2)>COUNTIF($B2:$I2;$B2)`

Comment: sorry, that was supposed to be "please select `B2:I4`" of course

Comment: Are you sure the condition (second argument of `COUNTIF`) should be `$B2` and not `B2`? Also that will highlight the parameters as well, which is not supposed to happen (at least not independently)...

Comment: did you try it? Yes I think it should be `$B2`. If you do not want the parameters highlighted then you will need 4 sets of conditional formatting rules. Use the condition formula that is exactly the same for all of them (as I wrote above), but have the first one "Apply to" `B2:B4`, the second apply to `D2:D4`, the third to `F2:F4`, and fourth to `H2:H4`

Comment: alternatively use this single formula (which should prevent the parameters from being highlighted):  please select B2:I2 and put this (exactly) in the conditional formatting box: =AND(not(isnumber(B2)),COUNTIF($B$2:$I$4;$B2)>COUNTIF($B2:$I2;$B2))

Comment: ok, you're right. It should be B2, i got confused with a simmilar question on here earlier... sorry.    `=AND(not(isnumber(B2)),COUNTIF($B$2:$I$4;B2)>COUNTIF($B2:$I2;B2))`

Comment: Ooh, that `AND` is genius. This one works, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you could just do  (no need for an IF() when used in Conditional Formatting Formula box:

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$I$4;$B2)>COUNTIF($B2:$I2;$B2)`

---

This single formula should prevent the parameters from being highlighted

- select B2:I2 and
- put this (exactly) in the conditional formatting box: `=AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(B2));COUNTIF($B$2:$I$4;B2)>COUNTIF($B2:$I2;B2))`

Comment: Accepting this answer because of the great help in the comments above and the modified formula for my exact data structure, thank you very much.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that when selecting the data area, one must start at B2. That cell will be displayed white while all the other selected cells will be blue. If another cell is white, it breaks. This can be fixed by changing all references to the first selected cell. For example, if I mark the area starting at I4, I will replace all instances of `B2` with `I4` and `$B2:$I2` with `$B4:$I4`, then it still works as intended. On an unrelated note, the first `,` in your formula should be a `;`.

Comment: That is how conditional formatting works, if you select the cells. You can also change the "applies to" box for each conditional formula when you create it. The , & ; are dependent on your location settings, but I've changed it so that they are consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
=(COUNTIF($B$2:$E$4,B2)-COUNTIF($B2:$E2,B2))>0
```

The first countif counts all instances in the range, the second one subtracts the count of entries in the row. If there are more instances in the entire range than in the row it returns true

Comment: Alright, that works. Unfortunately, the exact structure of my data breaks it... I'm editing the question right now, wasn't aware this was the problem...

Comment: By the way, the `COUNTIF` functions need `;` instead of `,` in my Excel in order to work in the first place. I'm using 2010.