# Excel: compare and format cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

[image: example]

I have 2 columns with different values.
What I wish to accomplish is this:

```
1. if value of any cell in A is not in any cell of B > make cell blue
2. if value of any cell in B is not in any cell of A > make cell yellow
3. if value of any cell in A is also in any cell of B > make cell green
```

A2 found in B2, make A2 & B2 both green

A3 nowhere in B, make A3 blue

A4 found in B3, make both green

B8 nowhere in A, make B8 yellow

A8 nowhere in B, make A8 blue

I hope this makes sense and is possible with conditional formatting. I couldn't figure out the formula to use for this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911884/highlight-duplicates-ignoring-same-row/25912999#25912999  - have a read and see if you can work it out yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please select A2:A8, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=MATCH($A2,$B$1:$B$10,0)
```

with green formatting and another rule:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH($A2,$B$1:$B$10,0))
```

with blue formatting.

Select B2:B8 and repeat the above with:

green: `=MATCH($B2,$A$1:$A$10,0)` and yellow: `=ISERROR(MATCH($B2,$A$1:$A$10,0))`.